# How do I remove a non existen vehicle from GeoFire database?

Tags: android, geofire

I am running the GeoFire's SFVeihcle Demo and onExit runs properly on device the same with onKeyExited.
But it not removes the key from map!!!
I am running the following:

```
@Override 
    public void onKeyExited(String key) { 
        // Remove any old marker 
        Marker marker = this.markers.get(key); 
        if (marker != null) { 
            marker.remove(); 
            this.markers.remove(key); 
        } 
    }
```

The key is disappearing from map when I set the focus outside the vehicle, but when I move back the focus to that area, it returns even I closed my other app.
How do I remove a key completely from Database?